# Error 424 when trying to copy ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the values from a table in one sheet called reg) into a table in another sheet (called staff) in the same workbook.

I get a runtime error '424' when I execute the following:

```
staff.Range("TableNewEmplInput").Value = Reg.Range("TableNewEmplData").Value
```

Can anyone explain to me why this error is occurring?

Comment: It works for me provided the sheetname and the table name are correct.

Comment: Unless those are the codenames of the sheets you should use `Sheets("staff").Range("TableNewEmplInput").Value = Sheets("Reg").Range("TableNewEmplData").Value`

Comment: Good one @Rory on the Codename. I believe that is the issue :)

Comment: @DanWagner: Please do not change the tag. :) These are the correct tags.

Comment: My apologies, must have accidentally changed those -- thanks for cleaning that up @SiddharthRout!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute a `Range` copy the way you are above by getting rid of `.Value` from the left side of the assignment above:

```
Dim Staff As Worksheet, Reg As Worksheet '<~ assume these are named and defined
'...
Set Staff = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("staff")
Set Reg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reg")
staff.Range("TableNewEmplInput") = Reg.Range("TableNewEmplData").Value
```

That being said, I would recommend adjusting the design of this sheet to use easier-to-differentiate named ranges...